# Angular directive access template elements from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm using an angular directive to add a reusable popup to various elements. Due to styling constraints, rather than adding the popover to the element, I need to add it to the document body. I would later like to access it in my controller - how would I go about doing so?

```
.controller 'slUserCtrl', ($element) ->
   $element.popup
      hoverable: true
      position: 'bottom right'
      popup: # What do I put here to get the "template" DOM element?

.directive 'slUser', ($document) ->
   template = $templateCache.get 'users/sl-user.html'

   return {
      restrict: "A"
      controller: 'slUserCtrl'
      compile: (elem, attrs) ->
         angular.element(document.body).append template
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to display a modal popup by attaching it to the document body, you are manipulating the DOM. There is one place where DOM manipulation is Ok, and that's the directive's link function.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
});

app.directive('modal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: 'element',    
    controller: function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.dialog = { show: false };
    },
    link: function(scope, element,attr,ctrl, transclude) {      
      transclude(function(clone, scope) {
        scope.$watch('dialog.show', function (val) {
          if (val) {
            clone.css('display', 'block');  
          }
          else {


            clone.css('display', 'none');                
          }
        });
        angular.element(document.body).append(clone);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    Hello World!
    <button ng-click="dialog.show = !dialog.show">Open Modal </button> {{test}}
    <div modal>
         This is a modal dialog
    </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that I have many of these popups attached to an element with ng-repeat. Is there a way to solve this without rootscope?